# Why does Eclipse store plugins in different folders and how to fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just found out that my Eclipse stores plug-ins, especially ones from companies in `C:\Users\<name>\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1709980481\plugins` instead of the default Eclipse directory `C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins`.

I didn't specify that folder in any way and have no idea why Eclipse does that.

Does this affect the use of the plug-ins?

Can I change the default setting for this directory?

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to a later version of Eclipse? I don't think 4.x does that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eclipse does this when it does not have write access to the install directory. Everything should still work OK.

Comment: +1 correct, but not always everything works as should - Once I had to change the install folder rights to have some plugins working. I can't remember which...

Comment: Hey @greg - as StackOverflow's most knowledgeable person on Eclipse Plugin developement - what's the books/sites we should be reading to get good at this stuff? I'm drawing a bit of a blank for decent reading matter... :(